NX with React Native, trying to build the app to my device or trying to make a release build on xcode or on AndroidStudio
i has been trying to implement somes apps on RN with a nx monorepo, all was working good but realized that when i try to build the app on debug mode on simulator, its works fine but on my device i get the next error:
enter image description here
At the same time when i am trying to make a release version on xcode or android studios, i am getting the same error.
Some extra info: I i realized too that if i try to start metro from the app and not with the nx application_name start, its works but when the application is opened, i get the same error again.
can i get some help, please?
I am hoping to make the release version with android studios and xcode.
